# 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: angular, compilation, try-catch

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {
  private url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    
    getPosts(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
    createPost(post){
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post));
    }
    updatePost(post){
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + post.id, JSON.stringify(post));
    }
    deletePost(id){
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
      .catch((error:Response)=>{
       return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
        
      });
    }
  }
```

here compile time error in .catch part.
I just want to perform error Handeling. and use catch by importing it but it will show error. that 'catch' does not exist on type
'Observable'

Comment: Use catchError https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: It looks like you are using Angular v6+, but not RxJS v6?

Comment: Have you added `rxjs-compat` package in your `package.json`

Comment: its "rxjs": "~6.3.3",

Answer (score 2):

Use error handling functions of rxjs [error handling - catch](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html). Your code will look like this:

```
deletePost(id){
return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
   .pipe(catchError(err => of(new AppError(err))))
}
```